# How do I remove the apt package index?

Tags: apt, docker

I've noticed with many Debian/ubuntu based docker images, you have to do an `apt-get update` before you install any packages. The cache is completely clear. I feel like I should do the same myself after I do my `RUN apt-update && apt-get install -y whatever`. I can't figure out how to do that. Is there a command, or do I just `rm -rf` q folder?

Comment: Maybe you should kill the urge to want to remove the apt package index? There is no need to do so.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you're building a docker image you try to keep it the smallest possible.
So who builds an image installing a package removes the cache to keep il small. The consequence is that you must run `apt-get update` if you want to install any package.

And as each docker command executed produces a layer, and its content will stay there "forever", once you finish to install the package you want to remove the cache too.

The two ways to do that are either one of the following:

1. `rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives /var/lib/apt/lists/*`.

OR

2. `apt-get clean`

> clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes everything but the lock file from /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.
>
> (source: man page)

Answer (score 14):

`rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

It's in the [Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/):

> when you clean up the apt cache by removing `/var/lib/apt/lists` it
>   reduces the image size, since the apt cache is not stored in a layer.

`/var/cache/apt/archives` doesn't have much data in it. Compare the `du` between those 2 dirs.

Answer (score 8):

As said [in David's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1117923/730194) , you usually `apt-get clean` or `rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives`.
This removes the package cache, which, according to the [manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html), contains downloaded packages themselves.

However, according to Docker's [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run), `apt-get clean` ***is done for you on any official Ubuntu/Debian image.***

---

The only thing left to clean in this case is the repository index cache : You would **only have to**

`rm -rf /var/cache/apt/lists`.

Answer (score 5):

Had a try with docker. `apt-get clean` still keep something(e.g. the index files). So, IMO, it is better to `rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives /var/lib/apt/lists` to get a smaller image.

Comment: image size went down by 40MB when removing the dirs directly vs. running `apt-get clean`